# how to get focus on jmenu so that i can use keyboard to operate

Tags: java, swing

i am creating a desktop application which has a window containing two frames, one inside another, internal frame containing JMENUBAR, so my question is how to get focus on first jmenu when this window opens, and it looks like:

[image]

below is the code for help

> import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
>
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>
> import java.util.Calendar;

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MMM-YYYY";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);



public Frame1() {
    initComponents();
    String dt = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    cur_date.setText(dt);
    setBindings();
}
private void setBindings(){
sales_invoicing.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

} 



private void formFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jInternalFrame1.setSelected(true);
        jInternalFrame1.requestFocus(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Carlsberg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cur_date = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    sales_invoicing = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu6 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu8 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem7 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem5 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem6 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu10 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu11 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu7 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu5 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            formFocusGained(evt);
        }
    });

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

    jLabel1.setText("");

    jLabel2.setText("");

    jLabel3.setText("");

    cur_date.setText("Nov 16,2013");

    jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

    jPanel2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

    jLabel5.setText("    Main Menu");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(118, 118, 118)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    sales_invoicing.setText("Sales Invoicing");
    sales_invoicing.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    sales_invoicing.setFocusPainted(true);
    sales_invoicing.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);

    jMenu6.setText("");

    jMenuItem1.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenu8.setText("");

    jMenuItem2.setText("");
    jMenu8.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuItem7.setText("");
    jMenu8.add(jMenuItem7);

    jMenuItem3.setText("");
    jMenu8.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenu6.add(jMenu8);

    jMenuItem4.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenuItem4);

    jMenuItem5.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenuItem5);

    jMenuItem6.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenuItem6);

    jMenu10.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenu10);

    jMenu11.setText("");
    jMenu6.add(jMenu11);

    sales_invoicing.add(jMenu6);

    jMenu7.setText("");
    sales_invoicing.add(jMenu7);

    jMenuBar1.add(sales_invoicing);

    jMenu2.setText("Stock Transfer");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu4.setText("Accounts");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu4);

    jMenu3.setText("Inventory");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

    jMenu5.setText("Exit");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu5);

    jInternalFrame1.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(170, 170, 170))
    );
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(109, 109, 109)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(136, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(72, 72, 72)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGap(185, 190, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(cur_date)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(4, 4, 4)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(cur_date))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
   
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Frame1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JLabel cur_date;
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu10;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu11;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu6;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu7;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu8;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem7;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JMenu sales_invoicing;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

}

please help me to write the code
i want focus on sales_invoicing so that i can operate it by keyboard

Comment: What do you mean focus on the menu? You mean you want is to popped open right when the program opens? Why would you want that?

Comment: Post link to your image.

Comment: _"i want focus on sales_invoicing so that i can operate it by keyboard"_ . Maybe you want to bind a key to the menu. Have you already done that?

Comment: Define an accelerator for the menu.  That is about all the 'easy access' that a user needs.

Comment: @alex2410 i have posted a link with it, check it out!,

Comment: @peeskillet i haven't do anything yet , how can i use binding in that
can you help me in code

--thanks in Advance

Comment: thanks @alex2410 for make my question good for ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to add a mnemonic to the menu and accelorators to the menu items. Something like this

```
private void setBindings(){
    sales_invoicing.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_4, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
}
```

The `sales_invoiceing` has a Mnemonic of `s`, so to open that menu, you <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

For the MenuItems they have accelerators using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key plus a number corresponding the to the menu item.

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SalesMenu extends JFrame {

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu sales_invoicing;

    JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem4;

    public SalesMenu() {
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        sales_invoicing = new JMenu("Sales Invoice");
        jMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        jMenuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        jMenuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");
        jMenuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Item 4");

        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem1);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem2);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem3);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem4);

        setBindings();

        menubar.add(sales_invoicing);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

    }

    private void setBindings(){
        sales_invoicing.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_4, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new SalesMenu();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

You can see the undeline under the mnemonic for the menu and you can see the accelerators for the menu items

**Edit** : run this example. It uses an internal frame. Once the program opens, the focus in on the internal frame, so you can access the key binding immediately. There's two class files. A test class, and the Internal frame class

`InternalFrameMenuTest.java`

```
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InternalFrameMenuTest extends JFrame {

    public InternalFrameMenuTest() {
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        InternalFrameMenu iframe = new InternalFrameMenu();
        desktop.add(iframe);
        iframe.setVisible(true);
        iframe.setFocusable(true);
        try {
            iframe.setSelected(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        add(desktop);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new InternalFrameMenuTest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`InternalFrameMenu.java`

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class InternalFrameMenu extends JInternalFrame {

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu sales_invoicing;

    JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    JMenuItem jMenuItem4;

    JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");

    public InternalFrameMenu() {
        super("Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);

        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        sales_invoicing = new JMenu("Sales Invoice");
        jMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        jMenuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        jMenuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");
        jMenuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Item 4");

        setBindings();

        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem1);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem2);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem3);
        sales_invoicing.add(jMenuItem4);

        menubar.add(sales_invoicing);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label);

        setSize(250, 250);
        setLocation(20, 20);
    }

    private void setBindings() {
        sales_invoicing.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem3.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_4, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: its works, but as you see my jmenu is inside the internal frame, for your code i have to click on internal frame first , so i think may be we have to set focus on internal frame first. Or is there any other method to solve it out. thanks in advance

Comment: See my edit. I set it up so it uses an internal frame

Comment: `iframe.setFocusable(true)`

Comment: its not working for me , have a look on my code i have edited

Comment: try and add the try/catch setSelected also. I hate lookint at auto genereated code, it's so messy

Comment: i got the answer for focusing in internal frames then i am using your code @peeskillet for shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

hey guys i got the answer to get focus on internal frame, see code below

```
private void formFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jInternalFrame1.setSelected(true);
        jInternalFrame1.requestFocus(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Carlsberg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```